# How to create route to array in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to export table records in CSV format. for that i want to pass array of ids to my controller's(say 'users') action (say 'export_csv').

I have created my route like this

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get "/export_csv/data", action: :export_csv, as: :export_csv
  end
end
```

And in my link_to tag i am passing it like this

```
export_csv_users_path(@data)
```

Which generates url like this

```
/users/export_csv/data?format[]=1&format[]=2&format[]=3&format[]=4&format[]=5&format[]=6&format[]=7&format[]=8&format[]=9&format[]=10&format[]=11&format[]=12&format[]=13&format[]=14&format[]=15&format[]=16&format[]=17&format[]=18&format[]=19&format[]=20&format[]=21&format[]=22&format[]=23&format[]=24&format[]=25&format[]=26&format[]=27&format[]=28&format[]=29&...
```

Due to which rails generates error

```
406 Not Acceptable
```

I want to know that is there any method through which i can pass array of id through route, something like this

```
/users/export_csv/data?format[]=[1,2,3,4,...]
```

Please suggest better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way is to pass such params as data in the post request.

try converting it to(and your call to the method also):

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    post "/export_csv/data", action: :export_csv, as: :export_csv
  end
end
```

Comment: In post method it comes with routing error --> No route matches "/users/export_csv/data"

Comment: Ok it solved my problem as i missed to define method => post in my link

Comment: hey Jeet,
do you mind letting me know what you finally went with?

Answer (score 2):

You can not pass array as parameter in url. If you want to pass array, you can combine array values to form a string:

In view:

```
= link_to 'url_name', export_csv_users_path(:data => @data.join(','))
```

Then you can get it in controller and split to generate array

```
array_element = params[:data].split(',')
```

Comment: this wont work if the number of ids in the are more then like 100 or so.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

if you think they are going to be more than that , you should convert it to post. Long should always be a o no no.

Comment: @sahildhankhar: you may be right, but still we can't send parameteres in the form of array either via get or post request.

Comment: hey aman , 
thanks for the feedback
with this request  
`/users/export_csv/data?format[]=1&format[]=2&format[]=3&format[]=4&format[]=5&format[]=6`
while accessing it in controller
params[:format] will give ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters

what i meant was that the reason he was getting 406 error was beacuse
format[] was getting repeated again and again in the url and it made size big.
there is no reason for join(",") and split in controller, it just helped decrease the size nothing much